# How can I solve this Integration problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let

$$\alpha = \int_0^1 (1-x^2)^{10}dx, \qquad\beta = \int_0^1 (1-x^2)^{9}dx $$

How do I express alpha in terms of beta?

Comment: use integration by parts on the first one

Comment: @Quantum Have *you*?

Comment: @ProfessorVector yes i have and t came out to be abeta function

Comment: You mean Euler's beta function ? @Quantum

Comment: $x^2 \mapsto x$.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \alpha = \int _ 0 ^ 1 \left( 1 - x ^ 2 \right) ^ { 10 } \, \mathrm d x = \int _ 0 ^ 1 \underbrace 1 _ { \text {(II)} } \cdot \underbrace { \left( 1 - x ^ 2 \right) ^ { 10 } } _ { \text {(I)} } \, \mathrm d x \\
= \left[ \underbrace { \left( 1 - x ^ 2 \right) ^ { 10 } } _ { \text {(I)} } \cdot \underbrace x _ { \text {(II)} } \right] _ 0 ^ 1 - \int _ 0 ^ 1 \underbrace { 10 \left( 1 - x ^ 2 \right) ^ 9 ( - 2 x ) } _ { \text {(I)} } \cdot \underbrace x _ { \text {(II)} } \, \mathrm d x \\
= 0 - 20 \int _ 0 ^ 1 \left( 1 - x ^ 2 \right) ^ 9 \Big( \left( 1 - x ^ 2 \right) - 1 \Big) \, \mathrm d x \\
= - 20 \underbrace { \int _ 0 ^ 1 \left( 1 - x ^ 2 \right) ^ { 10 } \, \mathrm d x } _ \alpha + 20 \underbrace { \int _ 0 ^ 1 \left( 1 - x ^ 2 \right) ^ 9 \, \mathrm d x } _ \beta $$
$$ \alpha = - 20 \alpha + 20 \beta $$
$$ \fbox { $ 21 \alpha = 20 \beta $ } $$
I hope this would suffice.